# 4 out of 8 gigs of ram used while Idle

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

I'm looking to troubleshoot my surface book 2 laptop that appears to have 5/8 gigs being used while idle.

Looking through similar posts, it appears as though most of the similar posts on superuser, it seems as though this is typically due to a bad driver.

I recently updated all of my drivers (using the drivers found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56261)), and was not successful in improving it.

Any ideas what I can do to improve this?

Here is a screenshot of my memory, and can provide whatever is requested for troubleshooting.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that I see the problem. Is it that not all 8 GB are already in use after a while? Since having memory actually used (even if only as cache for previously read data) is the goal performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

this is very common and happens on my machine as well.

1. are you facing any drop in the performance if no then please tell me if you have many background apps running or you have a antivirus software installed , in my case for the most part it is the antivirus software that runs in background and takes up bit of a memory.

2)if background apps are present type background apps in start menu and press enter and switch off the toggle key and then check if it still persists , if it does try uninstalling you antivirus if you have one.